Evaluating $\int_t^Te^{-a_r(T-x)}\cdot\sqrt{s^2(f(a_n))^2+n^2(f(b_n))^2+2snp\,f(a_n)f(b_n)\;}dx$, where $f(k)=\frac1k(1-e^{-k(T-x)})$
Hello:) i am currently working on the Jarrow Yildirim model with a Two factor Hull & White process. In order to derive a expected value i have to calculate this deterministic integral:
\begin{align*}
    \int_t^Te^{-a_r(T-x)}\cdot\sqrt{s^2(f(a_n))^2+n^2(f(b_n))^2+2snp\,f(a_n)f(b_n)\;}\;dx
\end{align*}
where $f(k)=\frac1k(1-e^{-k(T-x)})$, and $a_r,s,a_n,n,b_n,p$ are real numbers.
I have searched for suitable  trigonometric substitution formulas but without any success. 
Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this?
Thanks:)

For $p=2$ the quantity under the square root is actually a square! Maybe this could help starting.
Also, have you tried the change of variable $u = e^{-(T-x)}$ ?

Thanks for your comment:) I think the main problem is that we have 3 terms beneth the square root. So we cannot use trigonometric substitution.
